How to sort the Eigen::Matrix that have std::pair<int, int> and delete the duplicates of indices
I need a way to sort and delete the duplicates of row and column indices of a sparse matrix.
But at first I need to sort indices and later find a method to delete the duplicates.
Eigen::Matrix<std::pair<int, int>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> unsorted_indices; 

How can write a sort method for this? or method that I can achieve the both at once.

How is this structure supposed to work? It's a dense 2D matrix where each value is a pair. Is that really what you want, as opposed to a proper sparse matrix that you assign from triplets? And if you want to keep this, do you wish to remove dupes per row/column or over all? And how is the shape of the matrix supposed to change if you remove a different number of entries in each row/column?

This is to get the sparse pattern esp., number of non-zeros in each column or row. This matrix I try to get by dry running the loops. Then the indices are unsorted and duplicates.

That still makes no sense. If a single pair represents a row and column index, what does the row and column index of the matrix represent? What meaning has unsorted_indices(row, col)? Why is it not a vector<pair<int, int>>?

Then why does the data structure that you store those in (the matrix) also have rows and columns? Why is it not an unsorted list, meaning a simple vector?

pair<int,int> contains (row_i, col_j) and this is sparse. Matrix (i,j) contains a pair<int,int>. Once I know the number of non-zeros in a column/ row then I can reduce the cost of filling the Sparse matrix. I can easily achieve this with std::set<pair<int,int>>. Unfortunately with STL I can't the RAM back even after clearing the Set. When unknows grow over a million then things are very costly.

I need a Matrix to store the row_index and col_index.


I can easily achieve this with std::set<pair<int,int>> […] When unknows grow over a million then things are very costly

Matrix is the wrong data structure since you apparently make no use of it being two-dimensional. If std::set works for you, you can use a plain old std::vector
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> indices;
for(...)
  indices.emplace_back(row_i, col_j);
std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end());
indices.erase(std::unique(indices.begin(), indices.end()), indices.end());
indices.shrink_to_fit();

vector is more memory efficient than std::set (for the cost of a single entry in std::set including allocator overhead you can put 6 entries into a vector). The erase(unique(…) stuff is known as the erase-remove idiom
Hash table
If the number of duplicates is large, removing them early with a set-like structure may be better. However, std::set has a relatively high memory overhead and costly O(log(n)) insertion cost. std::unordered_set is more efficient with O(1) and has slightly lower memory usage but it requires you to write your own hash function.
Unless you need to avoid external libraries, use a flat hash table. They have a much lower memory overhead. Boost comes with one that supports std::pair out-of-the-box:
#include <boost/unordered/unordered_flat_set.hpp>

boost::unordered_flat_set<std::pair<int, int>> set;
for(...)
  set.insert({row_i, col_j});
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> indices(set.begin(), set.end());
std::sort(indices.begin(), indices.end());

Bitmap
As an alternative, you can use a simple bitmap. The memory consumption is then fixed to rows * cols / 8 byte as opposed to the at least 8 byte per entry in the hash table (not accounting for the hash table's overhead). So if your matrix is filled at least 1/64 (1.5%), the bitmap is more memory-efficient (or 1/320 compared to regular std::unordered_set). Scanning it for set bits also automatically produces a sorted sequence, saving us this step.
#include <bit>
// C++20, using std::countr_zero
#include <cstdint>
// using std::uint32_t

std::size_t words_per_row = (cols + 31) / 32;
std::vector<std::uint32_t> bitmap(words_per_row * rows);
for(...) {
  std::size_t index = row_i * words_per_row + col_j / 32;
  bitmap[index] |= 1 << (col_j % 32);
}
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> indices;
for(std::size_t row_i = 0; row_i < rows; ++row_i) {
  for(std::size_t word = 0; word < words_per_row; ++word) {
    std::uint32_t bits = bitmap[row_i * words_per_row + word];
    while(bits) {
      std::uint32_t bit_idx = std::countr_zero(bits);
      int col_j = word * 32 + bit_idx;
      indices.emplace_back(row_i, col_j);
      bits &= ~(1 << bit_idx); // clear bit
    }
  }
}


I will check whether I can claim the storage back after freeing the STL arrays. My mentor told, once the STL claim the storage freeing them cannot be used by any other array except STL by itself.

@jomegaA that's what the shrink_to_fit is for

In another case where I need to fill the triangle pairs and remove the duplicates the vector pose a little disadvantage. Before I could call, sort, unique, erase and shrink_to_fit the vector can grow really big. The set does not have that.

@jomegaA Try boost's unordered_flat_set to get rid of the duplicates, then copy the unique values into a vector and sort them at the end
